# Total number of installs not showing in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

My team has recently published several apps in Google Play Store but total number of installs is not being shown in our apps as it is shown in other apps.
Is there some time limit or minimum total installs required for this info to be shown?

here is the link to our apps. there are 3 apps but total number of installs is not being shown in any of them.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=AppNebula

Comment: Does it show correctly in google analytics?

Comment: wait for some time . google play take some time to display and update number of download . time vary from 1-2 days .

Comment: Thanks Ranjith and @WeakPersonality.....it came now....after some delay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got number of installed published. It took almost 2 days for the installs to appear.

Comment: Same for me too completed 2 days but not showing such and option how can i add it ,Check the following link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myoracle.com.quotes

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store indexing takes time. Somewhere between **1-2** days. Just be patient. It will appear. I had the same issue. I only had to wait a few days.